# Attempting to use insert_last_rowid()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I am attempting to assign the plan_recipe variable in the createPlan method with teh autoincremented id of the createPlanRecipe method. I've attempted to use the insert_last_rowid() method but am getting the error of Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Have I not done this correctly or is there another method I could use to do this?
Essentially how do I insert the id created from createPlanRecipe into variable plRecipe in createPlan()?

**Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_meal_plan);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    Intent a = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                    break;
                case R.id.recipes:
                    Intent b = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this,RecipeSearch.class);
                    startActivity(b);
                    break;
                /*case R.id.shoppingList:
                    Intent c = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this, ShoppingList.class);
                    startActivity(c);
                    break;*/
                case R.id.mealPlan:
                    Intent d = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this, MenuPlan.class);
                    startActivity(d);
                    break;
                /*case R.id.reminder:
                    Intent e = new Intent(CreateMealPlan.this, Reminder.class);
                    startActivity(e);
                    break*/
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    datepicker = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    ListRecipes();
    RecipeListAdapter.OnRecipeClickListener listener = new RecipeListAdapter.OnRecipeClickListener() {
        public void onRecipeClicked(int position, String recName) {
            Log.d("Recipe selected",  recName);
            recipe_name = recName;
        }

    };
    adapterRecipe = new RecipeListAdapter(this, listRecipe, listener);
    recipeList = findViewById(R.id.recipes);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recipeList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recipeList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recipeList.setAdapter(adapterRecipe);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create);

    // perform click event on submit button
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CreatePlan();

        }

        });
}
public void ListRecipes() {
    listRecipe.clear();
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
    String selectQuery = " SELECT recipe_name, image, image2, category" + " FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_RECIPE + "  GROUP BY recipe_name";
    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.d("Query", selectQuery);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Category category = new com.stu54259.plan2cook.Model.Category();
            category.setRecipe_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("recipe_name")));
            category.setImage(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("image")));
            category.setImage2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image2")));
            category.setCategory_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category")));
            listRecipe.add(category);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

}
public void CreatePlan(){
    editPlanName = findViewById(R.id.editPlanName);
    String plan_name = editPlanName.getText().toString();
    DatabaseManager db;
    int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datepicker.getMonth();
    int year = datepicker.getYear();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Integer d_name = day;
    Log.d("Date", String.valueOf(d_name));
    String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d_name);
    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" +year;
    db = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("Recipe name", recipe_name);
    db.createPlanRecipe(d_name, dayOfTheWeek, recipe_name);
    db.createPlan(plan_name, plan_recipe);

}
```

}

**Database snippet**

```
    public void createPlanRecipe(Integer date, String dayOfWeek, String recipe_name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(getINSERT_PLAN_RECIPE(date, dayOfWeek, recipe_name));
}
public void createPlan(String plan_name, Integer plRecipe) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select last_insert_rowid()",null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    if (c != null && (c.getCount() > 0)) {plRecipe = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));}
    db.execSQL(getInsertPlan(plan_name, plRecipe));
}
```

**Database**

```
 public static final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "CATEGORY";
public static final String TABLE_RECIPE = "RECIPE";
public static final String TABLE_MEAL_PLAN = "MEAL_PLAN";
public static final String TABLE_QUANTITY = "QUANTITY";
public static final String TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST = "SHOPPING_LIST";
public static final String TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES = "PLAN_RECIPES";
public static final String TABLE_COURSE = "COURSE";
public static final String TABLE_INGREDIENTS = "INGREDIENTS";
public static final String TABLE_MEASUREMENT = "MEASUREMENT";
public static final String TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE = "INGREDIENT_TYPE";
public static final String TABLE_ALLERGENS = "ALLERGENS";
public static final String TABLE_RECIPES_ALLERGENS = "RECIPES_ALLERGENS";
public static final String TABLE_FAVOURITES = "FAVOURITES";

// Common column names
private static final String COL_ID = "id";
private static final String COL_MEASUREMENT = "measurement";
private static final String COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE = "ingredient_type";
private static final String COL_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String COL_IMAGE = "image";

// Category column names
private static final String COL_CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
// Recipe column names
private static final String COL_RECIPE_NAME = "recipe_name";
private static final String COL_SERVINGS = "servings";
private static final String COL_CALORIES = "calories";
private static final String COL_PREPARATION_TIME = "preparation_time";
private static final String COL_METHOD = "method";
private static final String COL_COURSE = "course";
private static final String COL_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String COL_COST = "cost";
private static final String COL_IMAGE2 = "image2";
//Quantity column names
private static final String COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY = "ingredient_quantity";
private static final String COL_RECIPE = "recipe";
private static final String COL_INGREDIENT = "ingredient";
//Meal Plan column names
private static final String COL_PLAN_NAME = "plan_name";
private static final String COL_PLAN_RECIPE = "plan_recipe";

//Shopping List column names
private static final String COL_QUANTITY = "quantity";
private static final String COL_PLANID = "planID";

//Plan Recipes column names
private static final String COL_DATE = "date";
private static final String COL_DAY_OF_WEEK = "dayOfWeek";
//Course column names
private static final String COL_COURSE_NAME = "course_name";
//Ingredients column names
private static final String COL_INGREDIENT_NAME = "ingredient_name";
//Measurement column names
private static final String COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME = "measurement_name";
//Ingredient Type column names
private static final String COL_TYPE_NAME = "type_name";
//Allergens column names
private static final String COL_ALLERGEN_NAME = "allergen_name";

/* *************************************************************************************
 ************************* CREATE TABLE STATEMENTS **************************************
 ****************************************************************************************
 */
// Create Table Category
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORY = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_CATEGORY + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_CATEGORY_NAME
        + " TEXT," + COL_IMAGE + " INTEGER)";
// Create Table Meal Plan
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MEAL_PLAN = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_MEAL_PLAN + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_PLAN_NAME
        + " TEXT," + COL_PLAN_RECIPE + " NUMERIC," + " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_PLAN_RECIPE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES + "(" + COL_ID + "))";

// Create Table Recipe
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECIPE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECIPE + "(" + COL_ID +
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_RECIPE_NAME + " TEXT," + COL_DESCRIPTION
        + " TEXT," + COL_COURSE + " TEXT," + COL_SERVINGS + " INTEGER," + COL_CALORIES + " NUMERIC,"
        + COL_PREPARATION_TIME + " NUMERIC," + COL_METHOD + " TEXT," + COL_CATEGORY + " TEXT,"
        + COL_IMAGE + " INTEGER," + COL_IMAGE2 + " TEXT," + COL_COST + " NUMERIC," + " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_CATEGORY + ") REFERENCES " +
        TABLE_CATEGORY + "(" + COL_CATEGORY_NAME + "), FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_COURSE + ") REFERENCES " +
        TABLE_COURSE + "(" + COL_COURSE_NAME + "))";

// Create Table Quantity
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUANTITY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_QUANTITY + "(" + COL_ID +
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY + " NUMERIC, " +
        COL_RECIPE + " TEXT," + COL_INGREDIENT + " TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_RECIPE + ") " +
        "REFERENCES " + TABLE_RECIPE + "(" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + "), FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_INGREDIENT + ") " +
        "REFERENCES " + TABLE_INGREDIENTS + "(" + COL_INGREDIENT_NAME + "))";

// Create Table Shopping List
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST +
        "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + " INTEGER,"
        + COL_QUANTITY + " INTEGER," + COL_MEASUREMENT + " INTEGER," + COL_PLANID + " INTEGER," +
        " FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE + "(" + COL_ID + "), " +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_QUANTITY + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_QUANTITY + "(" + COL_ID + "), " +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_MEASUREMENT + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_MEASUREMENT + "(" + COL_ID + "), " +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_PLANID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_MEAL_PLAN + "(" + COL_ID + "))";
// Create Table Course
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_COURSE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COURSE + "(" + COL_ID +
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_COURSE_NAME + " TEXT," + COL_IMAGE + " INTEGER)";
// Create Table Ingredients
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_INGREDIENTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INGREDIENTS + "("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_INGREDIENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COL_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + " TEXT," + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + " TEXT, " +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_MEASUREMENT + "(" + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + "), " +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE + "(" + COL_TYPE_NAME + "))";
// Create Table Measurement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MEASUREMENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASUREMENT + "(" +
        COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + " TEXT)";
// Create Table Ingredient Type
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE +
        "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT)";
// Create Table Plan Recipes
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES + "(" +
        COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_DATE + " DATE," +
        COL_DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT," + COL_RECIPE_NAME + " TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + ") " +
        "REFERENCES " + TABLE_RECIPE + "(" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + "))";
// Create Table Allergens
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ALLERGENS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALLERGENS +
        "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_ALLERGEN_NAME + " TEXT)";
// Create Table Recipes_Allergens
private static final String CREATE_TABLES_RECIPES_ALLERGENS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RECIPES_ALLERGENS +
        "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_ALLERGEN_NAME + " TEXT," +
        COL_RECIPE + " TEXT," + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_ALLERGEN_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ALLERGENS +
        "(" + COL_ALLERGEN_NAME +"), " + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_RECIPE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_RECIPE +
        "(" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + "))";
// Create Table Favourites
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FAVOURITES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FAVOURITES + "(" +
        COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_RECIPE_NAME + " TEXT," +
        "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_RECIPE + "(" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + "))";


public final String INSERT_MEASUREMENT =
        "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MEASUREMENT + "("
                + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + ") values ";
public final String INSERT_INGREDIENT_TYPE =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE + "("
                + COL_TYPE_NAME + ") values ";
public final String INSERT_INGREDIENT =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_INGREDIENTS + "("
                + COL_INGREDIENT_NAME + "," + COL_DESCRIPTION + ","
                + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + "," + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + ") values ";
public final String INSERT_CATEGORY =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "("
                + COL_CATEGORY_NAME + "," + COL_IMAGE + ") values ";
public final String INSERT_COURSE =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_COURSE + "("
                + COL_COURSE_NAME + "," + COL_IMAGE + ") values ";
public final String INSERT_RECIPE =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_RECIPE + "("
                + COL_RECIPE_NAME + "," + COL_DESCRIPTION + ","
                + COL_COURSE + "," + COL_SERVINGS + ","
                + COL_CALORIES + "," + COL_PREPARATION_TIME + ","
                + COL_METHOD + "," + COL_CATEGORY + ","
                + COL_IMAGE + ","
                + COL_IMAGE2 + ","
                + COL_COST + ") values";
public final String INSERT_QUANTITY =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_QUANTITY + "("
                + COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY + ","
                + COL_RECIPE + ","
                + COL_INGREDIENT + ") values";
public final String INSERT_ALLERGEN =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_ALLERGENS + "("
        + COL_ALLERGEN_NAME + ") values";
public final String INSERT_RECIPES_ALLERGENS =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_RECIPES_ALLERGENS + "("
        + COL_ALLERGEN_NAME + ","
        + COL_RECIPE + ") values";
public final String INSERT_FAVOURITE =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_FAVOURITES + "("
        + COL_RECIPE_NAME + ") values";
public final String INSERT_PLAN_RECIPE =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_PLAN_RECIPES + "("
        + COL_DATE + ","
        + COL_DAY_OF_WEEK + ","
        + COL_RECIPE_NAME + ") values";
public final String INSERT_PLAN =
        " INSERT INTO " + TABLE_MEAL_PLAN + "("
        + COL_PLAN_NAME + ","
        + COL_PLAN_RECIPE + ") values";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an alias like `id` for the column that is returned by `last_insert_rowid()`:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select last_insert_rowid() as id", null);
```

Then instead of:

```
if (c != null && (c.getCount() > 0)) {plRecipe = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));}
```

do this:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {plRecipe = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));}
```

Without the alias of the column, you should directly use `0` inside `c.getInt()`:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {plRecipe = c.getInt(0);}
```

Comment: I get this error Cannot resolve method 'moveTofirst' in 'Cursor' when trying to implement this solution?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MEAL_PLAN has no column named plan_recipe (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MEAL_PLAN(plan_name,plan_recipe) values ( 'Plan Name','14')

Comment: I've included a relative portion of the database but I can't see any error.

Comment: @RevansArden This answer is about the problem/error as you described it in your question. If now there is another issue you can post a new question where you explain what the problem is.